# Money Combinations

Tags: combinations

Please note that I have tried to the best of my ability everything but in my work I have to assume distinct possibilities which means that 5 pennies and 1 nickel are different amounts. I am lost.

Chance has quarters, dimes, and nickels. His mother makes him give 6 coins to his sister. How many different monetary values can he give his sister?

Comment: I don't understand how pennies even come into consideration.

Comment: Presumably he has at least 6 of each type of coins as well?

Comment: It was an example I suppose and I wasn't thinking that well because it was 2 in the morning. No rush though.

Answer (score 0):

A nickel is 5 cents, a dime 10 and a quarter 25. All are multiples of 5, so we can divide 5 out and we'll get the same result:

> I choose six times from {1, 2, 5} and sum up my choices. How many possible sums can I get?

This is easy enough to list.

- Number of fives in selection *f* = 0: {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} (Σ = 6), {2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} (7), … {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} (12)
- *f* = 1: {5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} (Σ = 10), …, {5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2} (15)
- *f* = 2: {5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1} (14), …, {5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2} (18)
- …
- *f* = 5: {5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5} (30)

The possible sums fall in the ranges 6-12, 10-15, 14-18, 18-21, 22-24, 26-27 and 30. Combining, this gives the ranges 6-24, 26-27 and 30, and there are 22 possible sums (monetary values) in total. This is the answer.

Related to your query is [A119651](https://oeis.org/A119651), which counts how many possible values *n* pennies/nickels/dimes/quarters can sum to.